# Scala.js CSS dependencies

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, scala.js

I'm trying to get Scala.js working with the bootstrap library.
Adding the js file was easy and straight forward:

```
jsDependencies +="org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.7-1" / "bootstrap.js" minified "bootstrap.min.js"
```

But now I've problems to add the bootstrap.css file.
I tried this line:

```
 "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.7-1" / "bootstrap.css" minified "bootstrap.min.css"
```

But adding a css file to the `jsDependencies` doesn't seem to work:

```
[error] (frontend/compile:resolvedJSDependencies) org.scalajs.core.tools.jsdep.JSLibResolveException: Some references to JS libraries could not be resolved:
[error] - Missing JS library: bootstrap.min.css
[error]   originating from: frontend:compile
[error] - Missing JS library: bootstrap.css
[error]   originating from: frontend:compile
```

Can anybody tell me how to get this working properly?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no Scala.js shortcut for it -- I just [include the CSS manually in my HTML](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajvm/app/views/client.scala.html#L28), just as you would in an ordinary non-Scala.js webpage.

jsDependencies has nothing to do with CSS, and really can't -- it expects to be working solely with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

[Weppack](https://webpack.js.org/) is able to inject CSS into your HTML page. You might want to look at [scalajs-bundler](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/index.html), a scala-js webpack wrapper.